# How can I create Xamarin.Forms Hidden Application or service and use it without launching it?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, sqlite-net, data-sharing

I want to have a centralised service app in Xamarin for database sharing between two other Xamarin apps. So, they both can work independent of each other and depends only on the centralised database. For that, I need to create a service app which can be instal either along the main apps or from play store directly and auto starts to initialise and run my sqlite database which my other apps can use whenever required.
So, any body have any idea about how to achieve this?

I'm right now focused on  creating an android service app in Xamarin.Forms which can initialise the database and can run as a background service without having to launch its main activity. But have not succeeded to achieve this. Is there any other approach or how should I solve this?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, But what you want is multiple applications have access to your SQLite db and what you want is a new application all together will create this for you?

Comment: It looks like it's a mobile server.Using a mobile app to connect database directly is not recommended by Google or Apple.Building a web server to connect database,and it can support data for mobile app.This will be a accepted solution.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/consuming/rest

Comment: @G.hakim you are right. My client has an existing app that has it's own local db. What he wants now is to create another app which can use the same db and operate on it. For that reason being, the approach we are following is to create a common service app which contains a local db(this app should be invisible to user and should auto start as soon as installed) and both of the other apps can access this centralised db and operate on it independently.

Comment: @NidhiSood Maybe this is not a application, it is Service in Mobile.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/services/

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT It's service in android but I'm looking something for iOS. As I've already done this part in android. Now, the problem is with iOS and I'm looking for same solution in iOS if possible.

Comment: @NidhiSood Okey.As far as I know, iOS must have a front-end interface, which seems to be more difficult to implement on iOS.If have idea ,will share here.

Comment: Thanks :) @JuniorJiang-MSFT